# Android studio stuck while updating

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, google-play-services

[image]

When I started android studio it gave me the popup at the bottom requesting to update and I clicked on it after some time it got stuck at unzipping (as given in Screen Shot1) and then when I clicked cancel and again checked for update it got stuck on the screen in the ScreenShot2.
Someone please help me resolve this problem as I am having problems in building games through unity due to incomplete package installed or provide me some link+path to download sdk tools and google play services externally.
Thank you very much in advance.

[Screen Shot 1 of Android Studio's update pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alGjb.png)

[Screen Shot 1 (after 51 min)of update pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bYMv.png)

Comment: Its downloading files. Please have patience. I have gone through the same problem earlier. :P

Comment: Its 13 minutes now.And it was just 18mb, still??

Comment: Why does it say Stopping ADB...  ?

Comment: Its 52 minutes now.Please help me out!!

Answer (score -1):

Open Task Manager (ctrl+alt+del, or right-click on the Windows Task Bar at the bottom) and right-click any rows of Android Studio and choose End task, then run Android Studio again and try to re-update.

Comment: I had closed and retried to update but stuck on same path. Though i didn&#39;t use task manager to close it. Will it help?